# Decompose shifted and overlapped two matrices into single matrix

Tags: r, matlab, matrix

I have a shift overlapped matrix from two similar (not identical) matrices. How to decompose this matrix into the original two matrices? Here is the R code to show this problem.

```
set.seed(42)
matrix1 <- matrix(1:25, nrow = 5)
matrix2 <- matrix1 + rnorm(25)
# shift overlapped
matrix3 <- cbind(matrix1[,1:2], 1/2*(matrix1[,3:5]+matrix2[,1:3]), matrix2[,4:5])
```

This is Matlab version:

```
matrix1 = [1:5;6:10;11:15;16:20;21:25]
matrix2 = matrix1 + randn(5)
matrix3 = [matrix1(:,1:2),0.5*(matrix1(:,3:5)+matrix2(:,1:3)),matrix2(:,4:5)]
```

In this case, I could only see `matrix3` and know that the matrix has two column shifted.

Then how to decompose `matrix3` back into `matrix1` and `matrix2`? I don't expect a high accuracy but I have no idea and there should be some solutions in R or Matlab.

To make it more intuitional, two similar pictures were overlapped with known shift (e.g. 10px at the right) and I want to decompose the overlapped picture into those two similar pictures.

Comment: Why Matlab tag?

Comment: @LuisMendo Maybe this issue could be solved by matlab

Comment: You'll get a better chance for that if you explain what the code should do for non R users

Comment: What makes you think that you can find the two original matrices? Your problem is kind of like: "`x + y = 10`, find `x` and `y`".

Comment: You say the two matrices are "similar"... IMHO, the best you can do without further informations is: `m1 <- cbind(matrix3[, 1:2], matrix3[, 3:5]/2)` and `m2 <- cbind(matrix3[, 3:5]/2, matrix3[, 6:7])`.

Comment: Is there always a pattern in `m1`? For instance, the sequence `1:25`?

Comment: maybe lasso regression to learn each column of matrix3 one at a time. Although would work better the more different matrix1 and matrix2 are, (and if matrix1 was full rank)

Comment: @ChiPak Yes, there is a pattern in `m1`

Comment: @Scarabee Thanks for your edit. I updated demo code. In my case, the overlapped columns showed the mean instead of the sum.